# Control the current of a power supply using another variable power supply connected in series

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting

While disassembling a little electric oven (rated for 1300W at 230V), I scavenged one of the heating elements inside, which I measured its resistance to be about 40 Ohms (let's call it `Rload`).

Since it should be able to handle some power, I would like to use it as a "mild" load, for testing power supplies. For instance, let's say I have a 5V DC, 550 mA power supply (let's call it `Ptest`): once connected, `Rload` should draw around 125 mA, loading `Ptest` a bit.

I have a Rockseed RS310P programmable power supply, on which I can set voltage and current up to 30V and 10A (let's call it `Pvar`). I thought about connecting `Pvar` and `Ptest` in series with `Rload`, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0hkA3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My idea is that, by setting the current limit of `Pvar`, the PSU will act as a constant current source and it will adjust its voltage to whatever is needed to mantain that current. The current will cause a certain voltage drop (`Vload`) at the load, and given that `Vload` must be equal to `Vtest + Vvar`, `Pvar` will adjust its voltage to be `Vvar = Vload - Vtest`.

For instance, given the current limit `Iset = 250 mA`, `Vload = Iset * Rload = 10V`, `Vvar = Vload - Vtest = 5V`: in order for 250 mA to flow through `Rload`, `Vvar` must be 5V. But, since everything is connected in series, this means that 250 mA are flowing through `Ptest` aswell, which is the effect I'm interested about: from `Ptest` point of view, it should be like a load which is drawing 250 mA.

Thus, setting the current limit could drive this makeshift "variable load" within a certain range: in this case, I should be able to go from a little above 125 mA up to 875 mA (by setting `Vvar` to 30 V, which means `Vload = Vtest + Vvar = 35 V`.

I know proper variable loads exist, but I would like to know if this could really work: theoretically it should, although I don't know much about power supply topologies (except really simple unregulated ones) so I'm not sure about practical pitfalls or even safety hazards involved.

How about connecting a battery instead of a power supply as test source? It should discharge the battery at a specific current.

Comment: Some amateurs creating schematics which going against engineer's logic, and it works. To find out if you right experiments needed. Easier will be to assemble some current stabilization. A lot of solutions exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work just fine as long as your variable power supply supports series connections (its output must be floating, not grounded). Keep in mind that you might damage your PSU under test if it too goes into current limiting, as the variable supply might drive a reverse voltage into it. It might be safer to use the variable supply in constant voltage mode, which will result in the overall current dropping if one of the two PSUs goes into current-limiting mode accidentally.

Comment: I checked my PSU: the output is floating, so I should be good to go